# Dynamic PIVOT in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, pivot

i rare use PIVOT in sql server but now requirement is something that i have to use PIVOT.

my table structure is something like

```
CurDate               Warranty_Info
-------               -------------
01/01/2009                50
01/05/2009                30
01/03/2009                220
01/01/2010                40
01/06/2010                10
01/02/2010                0
01/01/2011                10
01/05/2012                420
01/05/2013                130
```

now i have to show the data in this way

```
Month     2009     2010    2011    2012   2013
-----     ----     ----    ----    ----   -----
JAN        10       0       11      32      98
FEB        20       10      21      11      44
MAR        0        224     33      77      31

UPTO

DEC
```

1) data should display month wise order....so jan first
2) if no data exist in any month then month name will come with 0 as value for that month.

i tried but fail. here is my sql by which i tried.

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT DateName(month,DateAdd(month,Month(CurDate),-1))  as [Month], 
        YEAR(CurDate) AS WarrantyYear,
        Warranty_Info 
        FROM eod_main) AS D
  PIVOT (
    SUM(Warranty_Info)
    FOR WarrantyYear IN (
      [2009],[2010],[2011],[2012],[2013]
    )
  ) AS P
  ORDER BY DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH, [Month] - 1, 0))
```

and i tried to generate sql dynamically this way.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @PivotTableSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @StartYear AS INT,
        @EndYear  AS INT

SET @StartYear=2009
SET @EndYear=2013

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(Year(CurDate))
                    from eod_main 
                    WHERE Year(CurDate)>=@StartYear AND Year(CurDate) <=@EndYear
                    group by Year(CurDate)
                    order by Year(CurDate)
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')



SET @PivotTableSQL = N'
  SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT Month(CurDate), YEAR(CurDate) AS WarrantyYear,Warranty_Info FROM eod_main) AS D

  PIVOT (
    SUM(Warranty_Info)
    FOR WarrantyYear IN (
      ' + @cols + '
    )
  ) AS PivotTable
'
print @PivotTableSQL
```

but some where i am facing problem like
1) display month name
2) order by month no
3) null value show show 0 instead of NULL
4) if no data exist for any month then month name should display with 0 value.

please guide me how to achieve it. thanks

### UPDATE

```
DECLARE @query varchar(max)
DECLARE @StartYr INT
DECLARE @ENDYr INT
declare @years varchar(max), @yearsColumns varchar(max)

SET @StartYr=2011
SET @EndYr=2013

SELECT 1 mID, 'January' as month  into #tempMonths   UNION ALL 
SELECT 2,'February' as month     UNION ALL 
SELECT 3,'March' as month     UNION ALL 
SELECT 4,'April' as month     UNION ALL 
SELECT 5,'May' as month     UNION ALL 
SELECT 6,'June' as month     UNION ALL 
SELECT 7,'July' as month     UNION ALL 
SELECT 8,'August' as month     UNION ALL 
SELECT 9,'September' as month     UNION ALL 
SELECT 10,'October' as month    UNION ALL 
SELECT 11,'November' as month    UNION ALL 
SELECT 12,'December' as month  


SELECT @years=COALESCE(@years+',','')   +'['+ cast(years as varchar(4))+']',
@yearsColumns=COALESCE(@yearsColumns+',','')   +'isnull(['+ cast(years as varchar(4))+'],0) 
as ['+cast(years as varchar(4))+']'
from  (select distinct YEAR(CurDate)  years from EOD_Main
WHERE YEAR(CurDate)>=@StartYr AND YEAR(CurDate)<=@EndYr
) as x

SET @query = 'Select months,'+@yearsColumns+' from (
select distinct mID, YEAR(CurDate)  years,[MONTH] months,  
isnull(Warranty_Info,0) as Warranty_Info  from EOD_Main
      right join #tempMonths on datename(month,CurDate ) =[month] 
) as xx
PIVOT 
(
SUM(xx.Warranty_Info) FOR years IN ('+@years+')
)
as pvt ORDER BY mID'
--PRINT @query
EXEC(@query)
```

drop table #tempMonths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Find the Below Solution, i hope that it is help full to you

```
    SELECT  CAST('01/01/2009' AS date)    CurDate   , 50 Warranty_Info INto #temp UNION all SELECT
     CAST('05/01/2009'   AS date)            ,  30      UNION all  SELECT
     CAST('03/01/2009'   AS date)            ,  220     UNION all  SELECT
     CAST('01/01/2010'   AS date)            ,  40      UNION all  SELECT
     CAST('06/01/2010'   AS date)            ,  10      UNION all  SELECT
     CAST('02/01/2010'   AS date)            ,  0       UNION all  SELECT
     CAST('01/01/2011'    AS date)           ,  10      UNION all  SELECT
     CAST('05/01/2012'   AS date)            ,  420     UNION all  SELECT
     CAST('05/01/2013'   AS date)            ,  130     

    SELECT 1 mID, 'January' as month  into #tempMonths   UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2,'February' as month     UNION ALL 
    SELECT 3,'March' as month     UNION ALL 
    SELECT 4,'April' as month     UNION ALL 
    SELECT 5,'May' as month     UNION ALL 
    SELECT 6,'June' as month     UNION ALL 
    SELECT 7,'July' as month     UNION ALL 
    SELECT 8,'August' as month     UNION ALL 
    SELECT 9,'September' as month     UNION ALL 
    SELECT 10,'October' as month    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 11,'November' as month    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 12,'December' as month  

        declare @years varchar(max), @yearsColumns varchar(max)

    SELECT @years=COALESCE(@years+',','')   +'['+ cast(years as varchar(4))+']',
    @yearsColumns=COALESCE(@yearsColumns+',','')   +'isnull(['+ cast(years as varchar(4))+'],0) as ['+cast(years as varchar(4))+']'

     from  (select distinct YEAR(CurDate)  years from #temp) as x
    print @years

    DECLARE @query varchar(max)= '
    select months,'+@yearsColumns+' from (
   select distinct mID, YEAR(CurDate)  years,[MONTH] months,  isnull(Warranty_Info,0) as Warranty_Info  from #temp
          right join #tempMonths on datename(month,CurDate ) =[month] 
    ) as xx
    PIVOT 
    (
    SUM(xx.Warranty_Info) FOR years IN ('+@years+')
    )
    as pvt ORDER BY mID'
    PRINT @query
    EXEC(@query)
```

output islike below

```
months    2009         2010       2011         2012        2013
--------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
January   50          40          10          0           0
February  0           0           0           0           0
March     220         0           0           0           0
April     0           0           0           0           0
May       30          0           0           420         130
June      0           10          0           0           0
July      0           0           0           0           0
August    0           0           0           0           0
September 0           0           0           0           0
October   0           0           0           0           0
November  0           0           0           0           0
December  0           0           0           0           0
```

if it is give accurate result don't forget to make a vote.

Comment: the script is giving error when i run it in sql server 2005. please have a look and fix it. thanks

Comment: can you please specify the type of error, i don't have sqlserver 2005

Comment: sorry i test ur code in sql server 2008 and it works. great :) thanks

Comment: some time in my case year number is not getting sequential means some time 2010 is coming first and then may be 2009 is coming. any idea which area need to rectify. can we arrange the year always order wise. thanks

Comment: SELECT @years=COALESCE(@years+',','')   +'['+ cast(years as varchar(4))+']',
         @yearsColumns=COALESCE(@yearsColumns+',','')   +'isnull(['+ cast(years as varchar(4))+'],0) as ['+cast(years as varchar(4))+']'

          from  (select distinct YEAR(CurDate)  years from #temp) as x ORDER BY years

Comment: if possible please have a look at this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489623/sql-server-pivot-output-issue